# EKEventStore passed NSDate and subtracts a couple months

Tags: iphone, objective-c, events, calendar, ekevent

I'm working to add an event to the iPhone calendar and everything goes as planned, however, a little over a month and a half is being subtracted from my startDate. When the date is actually Feb 14, 2012... the event date added to the calendar is Dec 25, 2011.

expiresOn.text is a string like "Feb 14, 2012". Can anyone offer insight as to what may be causing the problem?

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

EKEvent *event  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
event.title     = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ Expiration", self.navigationItem.title];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 

NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0800 %@", expiresOn.text];

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"hhmm MMM dd, YYYY"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];

event.startDate = date;
event.endDate   = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:600 sinceDate:event.startDate];

[event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
NSError *err;
[eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err]; 

EKEventViewController *viewController = [[EKEventViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle: nil];
viewController.event = event;
viewController.allowsEditing = YES;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have a case sensitive typo in the set up for your formatter.

Use:

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy"];
```

And I hope this helps!